# What is the probability distribution function for the product of two correlated Gaussian random variable?

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose we have pair $(X,Y)\sim Normal([\mu_x,\mu_y],{{\sigma_x^2\atop\rho \sigma_x\sigma_y } {\rho \sigma_x\sigma_y \atop \sigma_y^2} }] $
How is $U=X\cdot Y$ distributed?
I've tried to compute this by substituting y=u/x  in the bivariate normal pdf and taking integral(from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ with respect to x. I find the pdf of U as the sum of two  exponential distributions(one for U<0 and one for U>0) that are weighted unequally. Is my method valid, or do I have to deal with cumulative distribution functions instead?

Answer (score 11):

Arkadiusz gives the answer in the case of two independent Gaussians.  A simple technique to reduce the correlated case to the uncorrelated is to diagonalize the system.  The intuition which I use is that for two random variables, we need two "independent streams of randomness," which we then mix to get the right correlation structure.

Let $X \sim N(0,\sigma_x)$ and let $Z \sim N(0,1)$ be two independent normals.  Define

$Y = \tfrac{\rho \sigma_y}{\sigma_x}X + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_y Z$.

Check that $\mathbb E Y^2 = \sigma_y^2$ and $\mathbb E XY = \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y$; this completely determines the bivariate Gaussian case you're interested in.

Now, $XY = \tfrac{\rho \sigma_y}{\sigma_x} X^2 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_y XZ$.  The $X^2$ part has a $\chi^2$-distribution, familiar to statistics students; the $XZ$ part is comprised of two independent Gaussians, hence Arkadiusz's answer gives the distribution of that random variable.

**Edit:**  As Robert Israel points out in the comments, I made a mistake in my final conclusion:  the random variables $X^2$ and $XZ$ are uncorrelated, though certainly not independent.  Nonetheless, the problem is essentially resolved at this point, since we have reduced the problem of understanding the product $XY$ to a sum of uncorrelated random variables $X^2$ and $XZ$ with known distributions.

Comment: No, the density of the sum of two _independent_ random variables is the convolution of their density functions.  Unfortunately, $X^2$ and $XZ$ are certainly not independent (although they are uncorrelated).

Comment: @Robert Israel, thank you for your comment.  Of course, you are absolutely right.  I have edited my response to fix this error.

Comment: How does it solve the problem to represent XY as a sum of uncorrelated random variables with known distributions?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that no closed-form expression is known for the correlated case.

For the uncorrelated case $\rho=0$ the distribution of XY is $\frac{1}{\pi \sigma_x \sigma_y}K_0(\frac{|u|}{\sigma_x \sigma_y})$, where $K_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. This distribution differs from the distribution you gave (is it Laplace distribution?). A notable difference: it has kurtosis of 6 (sharper peak), comparing to 3 for Laplace distribution.

[Normal Product Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html)

[On the Frequency Function of xy. C.Craig, 1936](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/GaussianProduct1934.pdf)

Edit: answering the second question, the method is valid, but my guess is that the Jacobian determinant was skipped while doing the substitution.

Answer (score 4):

LaGatta's answer nails it, and may be useful for drawing simulations, etc.

This is just a note to remind that if one is only interested in the mean of the product of normally-distributed (possibly correlated) random variables, then the answer is straightforward, using the identity $\operatorname{E}XY= \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) + (\operatorname{E}X)(\operatorname{E}Y)$.

Comment: That is a nice observation, pedro.  If one is furthermore interested in any higher moments $\mathbb E (XY)^k$, then I suggest using the decomposition $Y = \tfrac{\rho \sigma_y}{\sigma_x}X + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_y Z$ and using the independence of $X$ and $Z$.  As Arkadiusz says, there is likely no known closed-form expression for the product, though in practice we can estimate probabilities using Chebyshev's inequality and arbitrary moments.